# Oracle 12c: WHERE NOT vs WHERE ... OR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to select rows where **RN=1** or **ID is NULL**.
Which condition is more efficient and fast?

```
WHERE id IS NULL OR RN=1
```

vs

```
WHERE NOT (id IS NOT NULL AND RN >1)
```

Comment: First, `RN >1` is not the opposite of `RN=1`.
If you change `RN >1` to `RN<>1` than it would be the opposite.

That being said, After this fix the two are equivalent, and should produce the exact same execution plan.

Comment: The first one is correct, while the second one is incorrect.

Comment: Although they do different things, Oracle has a sophisticated optimizer and I would expect them to have very similar performance characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is the first one as the second approach will return you all the records even if the `ID` is not null.

> How the second approach will give you all the records?

```
WHERE NOT 
(id IS NOT NULL  
AND RN >1) -- this condition will be always false as you can not use > condition alone on rownum 

So <some_condition> AND False --> False

NOT (FALSE)  --> True
```

So, You should use the first condition: `WHERE id IS NULL OR RN=1`